# R: multiple x axis with annotations

Tags: r, plot

Is it possible to add more than one x-axis to a plot in R? And to put an annotation next to each scale?

Edit > here's the result of Nick Sabbe idea. For the annotation (a little text at the left of each axis), is it possible ?

[image]

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use the `line` argument of `axis()` to place an axis higher or lower, this way you can make multiple axes. With `mtext()` you can then add a label to the side. Do note that the plot itself is only on one scale so you need to rescale the points and labels of the other scale accordingly:

```
# Plot and first axis:
plot(1:10,1:10,bty="n",col="red",pch=16,axes=FALSE,xlab="",ylab="")
axis(2,0:11,las=1)
axis(1,0:11,line=1,col="red",col.ticks="red",col.axis="red")
mtext("Label 1",1,line=1,at=0.2,col="red")

# Secondary points and axis:
points(rnorm(10,50,20)/10, rnorm(10,5,2),pch=16, col="blue" )
axis(1,0:11,labels=0:11*10,line=3,col="blue",col.ticks="blue",col.axis="blue")
mtext("Label 2",1,line=3,at=0.2,col="blue")
```

[image]

Comment: I tried this with one more x-axis. the corresponding plot is drawn properly but the third axis seems to be going out of page range or something. Its not fully appearing. I used following addition, can you please reflect?

points(rnorm(10,50,20)/10, rnorm(10,5,2),pch=16, col="black" )
axis(1,0:11,labels=0:11*10,line=5,col="black",col.ticks="black",col.axis="black")
mtext("Label 3",1,line=5,at=0.2,col="black")

Answer (score 5):

You can use `?axis` for that. Parameter `at` is in the scale of the original axis of the plot, and you can pass `labels` to show other values.

You have to scale the axess labels yourself, though.

A very simple/silly example:

```
plot(1:10,1:10)
axis(side=4, at=c(3,7), labels=c(30,70))
```

Finally, note that most people consider adding multiple axes to a plot bad form...