# matlab multiple x axis one below another

Tags: matlab, axis

I am trying to create a matlab plot with multiple x-axis one below another and just one y-axis.

I have looked through the Mathworks file exchange and there are only suggestions/scripts for multiple y-axis. I would like to achieve something like [this question for R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8443820/r-multiple-x-axis-with-annotations).

Comment: Maybe one of these can help you: - [Using Multiple X- and Y-Axes](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/techdoc/creating_plots/f1-11215.html)
- [linkaxes](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/techdoc/ref/linkaxes.html)

Answer (score 4):

Here is an example solution if you only need a second axis for showing a different scale (Jeff_K's solution but more worked out):

```
first_axis = gca;
sqz = 0.12; %// distance to squeeze the first plot
set(first_axis, 'Position', get(first_axis, 'Position') + [0 sqz 0 -sqz ]);
ax2 = axes('Position', get(first_axis, 'Position') .* [1 1 1 0.001] - [0 sqz 0 0],'Color','none');
scale_factor = 42; %// change this to your satisfaction
xlim(get(first_axis, 'XLim') * scale_factor);
set(ax2, 'XScale', get(first_axis, 'XScale')); %// make logarithmic if first axis is too
```

Answer (score 3):

If you don't actually need to plot data on the secondary axes, and are just using them to show scale (like the example you linked to), you can do it simply by adding a second (or third, etc.) axis at the appropriate position, and setting the height very small:

```
ax2 = axes('Position',[0.1 0.1 0.8 0.001],'Color','none')
```

Then set the tick labels appropriately.

Answer (score -1):

you need to use a patch function for this.
Look here for more details: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/26550-myplotyy