# Double x and y-axis on imagesc and surf plot in Matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, axis

I want to put two values on the x-axis and y-axis of a imagesc and surf plot. Both plots plot the same values but the first is 2D and the second 3D.

The arrays that I want to put on the x-axis and y-axis have the same length and are both interesting to display in a single plot because they are related to each other.

So the x-axis and y-axis should look like the example solution in this post ([matlab multiple x axis one below another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11531762/matlab-multiple-x-axis-one-below-another)).

In case of a imagesc plot a double x-axis is not that difficult with the code of johan of the example solution and some random data.

```
Z = rand(20,30);
Y = 32.*(1:size(Z,1));
X = 1:size(Z,2);

scale_factor_xaxis=10;
scale_factor_yaxis=100;

figure(1)
imagesc(X,Y,Z)
set(gca,'XDir','normal','YDir','normal');
title('title')
xlabel('first x label')
ylabel('first y label')

first_axis = gca;
sqzx = 0.15; %// distance to squeeze the first x-axis plot
sqzy = 0.15; %// distance to squeeze the first y-axis plot
set(first_axis, 'Position', get(first_axis, 'Position') + [0 sqzx 0 -sqzx ]);

ax2 = axes('Position', get(first_axis, 'Position') .* [1 1 1 1e-12] - [0 sqzx 0 0],'Color','none');
xlim(get(first_axis, 'XLim') * scale_factor_xaxis);
set(ax2, 'XScale', get(first_axis, 'XScale')); %// make logarithmic if first axis is too
xlabel('second x label')
```

The next step should be to put also a second scale and label to the y-axis. But I this won't work with the next part of the code:

```
ax2 = axes('Position', get(first_axis, 'Position') .* [1 1 1 1e-12] - [0 sqzy 0 0],'Color','r');
ylim(get(first_axis, 'YLim') * scale_factor_yaxis);
set(ax2, 'YScale', get(first_axis, 'YScale')); %// make logarithmic if first axis is too
ylabel('second y label')
```

With this the second y-label is plotted next to the second x-axis and the second y-scale is a x-scale. But I do not understand the code enough to get this the way I describe.

Comment: I am highly cnfident that this approach wont work for 3D. The underliying method in that piece of code is to create a new plot (axis actually) that is 1e-12 heigth, therefore you can see the labels, but the pot is so small that it looks like a line. I doubt you can do that in 3D.