# Axis scale and labeling in MATLAB plot

Tags: matlab, plot

I've an FFT plot with negative and positive frequencies on X axis. I have a peak at Synchronous Frequency say 1X (1 times of fundamental frequency) and another peak sub synchronous frequency 0.30X (0.30 times of fundamental frequency). Now I want both the scaling to be labeled on the axis. I used the following code.

```
%for setting 1X frequency ( Synchronous frequency) 
set(gca,'XTick',-5000:2500:5000)
set(gca,'XTickLabel',{'-2X','-1X','0','1X','-2X'})

 %for setting 0.30X ( Sub harmonic frequency)
 set(gca,'XTick',-700:700:700)
set(gca,'XTickLabel',{'-0.3X','0','0.3X'})
```

But I see only the second scaling where as the first is not being plotted. Is there any other way to plot this with 2 absolute values. Please find reference image. Thanks in advance.

[image]

As you can notice in the figure. I've been able to label the first set of frequencies (1X,1 1/2X, etc). Now I also want the second set(-30X , 0.30X etc) as I indicated with arrow   arrow.

Comment: your last two commands overwrite the first two ones. But your image shows something completely different. Please share the code required to reproduce your problem

Comment: @PBCR Do you mind not using labels and use actual numerics instead?

Comment: @PBCR Please verify [my solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29790323/802378) and kindly accept if it's correct. Otherwise, let me know what needs to be changed/clarified!

Comment: I think you're wanting to put two x-axes on with slightly different scales, in which case see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11531762/

Answer (score 1):

i am not sure what are you looking for but maybe this will work for you

```
c=[-3:3 -3:0.3:3]; % spacing of 1 and 0.3
c=c.*2500; % 2500 is fundamental frequency
c=unique(sort(c));

for i=1:length(c)
    str1{i}=[num2str(c(i)/2500,'%.1f'),'X'];
end

plot(1,1,'+'); % random
hold on;
set(gca,'XTick',c,'XTickLabel',str1);
xlim([min(c) max(c)]);
```

Comment: Your solution leads to an obfuscated plot http://i.imgur.com/zO3XgGY.png

Comment: lol my solution is absolutely correct. try stretching the figure to full size of your little screen

Comment: I did and I saw the result. I misunderstood what the OP meant. I might edit my solution in the morning. Can you edit your solution so I can up vote? It's locked for me right now.

Comment: aah done, i should take anger management classes

Comment: I'll look at it in the morning. This is what happens when there's high level thinking after 13+ hours of work. I'll most likely delete mine. +1

Comment: That's pretty much exactly the same solution as my answer, do it all in one line.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe I'm missing something or have misunderstood your question, but why don't you lump it into one command? As mentioned in the comments, the last set of commands overwrite the first one.

```
set(gca,'XTick',[-5000 -2500 -700 0 700 2500 5000])
set(gca,'XTickLabel',{'-2X','-1X','-0.3X','0','0.3X','1X','-2X'})
```

Comment: I'm not 100% sure if this is what OP is looking for but perhaps you should include a way to plot the second axes and labels as well?

Comment: @krisdestruction Yes. this is not what I was looking for. I need both labels with different scales being seen on the plot. I've updated my figure.

Comment: @PBCR I'm afraid I still don't understand your question or what is it you are trying to do.