# Double ticklabel in Matlab

Tags: matlab, graph, plot, label, matlab-figure

I create the following image:

```
    figure
    y = [2 2 3 2 5 6 2 8 9];
    bar(y)
    name_x = {'0','1','2','0','1','2','0','1','2'}
    set(gca,'Xtick',1:9,'XTickLabel',name_x,'XTickLabelRotation',45)
```

[image]

Now I would like to write:

- under the first `0 1 2` "Group 1"
- Under the second `0 1 2` "Group 2"
- under the third `0 1 2` "Group 3"

In order to have something like the picture below:

[image]

How can I do this?

Comment: This has nothing to do with an answer - but why are you rotating the numbers?

Comment: because in my real figure I have words as xtick and rotating them makes the plot looking better...this is just a simplified example..

Comment: Did you try creating a second x-axis just for the tick labels? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11531762/matlab-multiple-x-axis-one-below-another

Answer (score 2):

You can add group names using [`text`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/text.html):

> `text(x,y,str)` adds a text description to one or more data points in the current axes using the text specified by `str`. To add text to one point, specify `x` and `y` as scalars in data units. To add text to multiple points, specify `x` and `y` as vectors with equal length.

You may want to use the `'Extent'` property of `text` objects to **center them horizontally** in each group. Also, you may need to vertically compress the axis a little to **make room** for the texts below.

```
%// Original graph
figure
y = [2 2 3 2 5 6 2 8 9];
bar(y)
name_x = {'0','1','2','0','1','2','0','1','2'};
set(gca,'Xtick',1:9,'XTickLabel',name_x,'XTickLabelRotation',45)

%// Add groups
groupX = [2 5 8]; %// central value of each group
groupY = -1; %// vertical position of texts. Adjust as needed
deltaY = .03; %// controls vertical compression of axis. Adjust as needed
groupNames = {'Gr. 1', 'Group 2', 'Grrroup 3'}; %// note different lengths to test centering
for g = 1:numel(groupX)
    h = text(groupX(g), groupY, groupNames{g}, 'Fontsize', 13, 'Fontweight', 'bold');
        %// create text for group with appropriate font size and weight
    pos = get(h, 'Position');
    ext = get(h, 'Extent');
    pos(1) = pos(1) - ext(3)/2; %// horizontally correct position to make it centered
    set(h, 'Position', pos); %// set corrected position for text
end
pos = get(gca, 'position');
pos(2) = pos(2) + deltaY; %// vertically compress axis to make room for texts
set(gca, 'Position', pos); %/ set corrected position for axis
```

[image]

Comment: I have problems when I change the ylim of the figure...do you know why by any chance? the text disappears

Comment: If you change `ylim`, you may need to set `groupY` as the first element of `ylim` minus `1` approximately