# 3 x-axis in matlab plot?

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

I need to plot a figure with 3 x-axes. Each axis is linked to the other by a mathematical formula. I want to do this because the x value can be seen as wavelength [nm], velocity [m/s] or energy [eV] and I want the reader to not have to convert it themselves on each graph.

I searched online and only found [something for 2 x-axes](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/graph-with-multiple-x-axes-and-y-axes.html), but no more.

**Edit**: I am using version R2011a.

So it should look like this, which I (obviously) didn't create in MATLAB:

[image: What I 'd like to plot (it is not done on matlab this one...)]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18224829/3978545), you can create a new `axes` object with near-zero height, so that it is essentially just the x-axis. Be aware that all actual plots must be done on the first axes as this is the area you can see!

Demo code:

```
% Create some plotting data and plot
x = 0:0.1:2*pi;   y = sin(x);
% Plot, can specify line attributes (like LineWidth) either 
% - inline: plot(x,y,'linewidth',2)
% - after: p1 = plot(x,y); p1.LineWidth = 2;
plot(x,y);
% Get current axes object (just plotted on) and its position
ax1 = gca;
axPos = ax1.Position;
% Change the position of ax1 to make room for extra axes
% format is [left bottom width height], so moving up and making shorter here...
ax1.Position = axPos + [0 0.3 0 -0.3];
% Exactly the same as for plots (above), axes LineWidth can be changed inline or after
ax1.LineWidth = 2;
% Add two more axes objects, with small multiplier for height, and offset for bottom
ax2 = axes('position', (axPos .* [1 1 1 1e-3]) + [0 0.15 0 0], 'color', 'none', 'linewidth', 2);
ax3 = axes('position', (axPos .* [1 1 1 1e-3]) + [0 0.00 0 0], 'color', 'none', 'linewidth', 2);
% You can change the limits of the new axes using XLim
ax2.XLim = [0 10];
ax3.XLim = [100 157];
% You can label the axes using XLabel.String
ax1.XLabel.String = 'Lambda [nm]';
ax2.XLabel.String = 'Velocity [m/s]';
ax3.XLabel.String = 'Energy [eV]';
```

Output:

[image: multiple x axes matlab]

---

**Edit**:
Before the [2014b graphics changes](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/graphics-changes-in-r2014b.html) you will need to make a couple of tweaks for getting and setting axes properties. The equivalent code would more heavily use the `set` command, and look something like this:

```
x = 0:0.1:2*pi;   y = sin(x);
plot(x,y);
ax1 = findobj(gca, 'type', 'axes')
axPos = get(ax1, 'Position');
set(ax1, 'Position', axPos + [0 0.3 0 -0.3]);
set(ax1, 'LineWidth', 2);
ax2 = axes('position', (axPos .* [1 1 1 1e-3]) + [0 0.15 0 0], 'color', 'none', 'linewidth', 2);
ax3 = axes('position', (axPos .* [1 1 1 1e-3]) + [0 0.00 0 0], 'color', 'none', 'linewidth', 2);
set(ax2, 'xlim', [0 10]);
set(ax3, 'xlim', [100 157]);
axes(ax1); xlabel('Lambda [nm]');
axes(ax2); xlabel('Velocity [m/s]');
axes(ax3); xlabel('Energy [eV]');
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! It works well :) And to increase linewidth it is ax1.LineWidth =.... ?

Comment: The line width of the plotted line? Please see the additional comments I've put in my code.

Comment: No, the width if the axis. I like it when it is thick ! usually I use this : `set(gca, 'FontSize', 13, 'fontName','calibri','LineWidth',2.0,'FontWeight','bold');` so now I juste have to change gca by ax1, ax2 and ax3 ? (I cannot try now, I don't have acces to my computer)

Comment: Ah yes, the axes linewidth can be changed the same as the plot linewidth, again please see my edit for demo of 2 methods, or you can use `set` like in your comment.

Comment: Again tanks a lot for your help :)

Comment: I have some problems. When I run your code it says that ax1 is not a structure. And in the console ax1 gives `>> 173.013`. Am I doing something wrong ?

Comment: If you go to Home > Help > About MATLAB, what is the "2015b" type version name? That is the one which will help you look up the correct documentation for your version.

Comment: It is 7.12.0.635 (R2011a).. so you can't help me for this version ?

Comment: Oh sorry I did not saw the new edit... I still have ax1=173 but I get what I wanted ! Thanks a lot for your help and patience.

Comment: Yes, if you see the link in my edit about the graphics changes, you will see that before MATLAB 2014b the axes handles *are* numerical instead of the struct you get in newer versions, so `ax1=173` is expected behaviour. No worries

Comment: If you can edit your code again : you need a `close all` and also a `clear` before all recompilation of the programme. Without this it send error message because width or heigh is negative.

Comment: *You* may need a `close all` or `clear` before your code because of previous actions, running that code on a clean workspace will give no errors... I'll upvote your comment so it rises to the top for other users, but leave my code for clarity. Consider removing any comments which are now obsolete so that things are clearer for future users. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of how you can do this:

```
msx = [1 50 60 90];
msy = [0 1 3 8];

lx = 90/4*[1 2 3 4]; % Scale the data with respect to the data that will use the "primary" X-axis
ly = [0 2 8 10];

evx = 90/19*[1 7 10 19]; % Scale the data with respect to the data that will use the "primary" X-axis
evy = [0 8 16 20];

figure
a=axes('units','normalized','position',[.1 .35 .7 .6],'xlim',[0 100],'xtick',0:10:100);
plot(lx, ly)
hold on
plot(msx, msy)
hold on
plot(evx, evy)
xlabel(a,'velocity m/s')
b=axes('units','normalized','position',[.1 .21 .7 0.000001],'xlim',[0 4],'color','none', 'xtick',0:1:10);
xlabel(b,'lambda nm');
c=axes('units','normalized','position',[.1 .10 .7 0.000001],'xlim',[0 19],'color','none', 'xtick',0:1:19);
xlabel(c,'energy eV');
```

For the position: specified as a four-element vector of the form [left bottom width height]. The default value of [0 0 1 1] includes the whole interior of the container. (see https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/axes-properties.html)

Output figure:
[image]