# How to set the second x-aixs in the graph?

Tags: r

```
x <- seq(0.5, 0.9, length = 400)
y <- dnorm(x,0.7,0.0458)
plot(x, y, type="l",  yaxt="n",ann=FALSE,bty="n", xaxt="n")
axis(1, at=seq(0.5,0.9,by=0.1), labels=c("","",0.7, 0.8, 0.9) )
mtext("Proportions", 1, at=0.9, line=2)
xx=c(0.8,seq(0.8,0.9,length=100),0.9)
yy= c(0,dnorm(seq(0.8,0.9,length=100),0.7,0.0458),0)
polygon(xx, yy, col = "gray", border = NA)
```

I get a good graph(graph1.jpg) with the code,how can i create the second line on the graph1.jpg,to change graph1.jpg into graph2.jpg?

This is a graph1.jpg.
[image]

This is a graph2.jpg.
[image]

Comment: duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8443820/r-multiple-x-axis-with-annotations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the function `axis()` there is an argument `line=` that determine in which line under plot axis is drawn. Setting this argument, for example, to `line=4` you can add another axis. But before `plot()` you should change margin setting to get more space under x axis with `par(mar=...))`.

```
par(mar=c(8,3,3,3))
x <- seq(0.5, 0.9, length = 400)
y <- dnorm(x,0.7,0.0458)
plot(x, y, type="l",  yaxt="n",ann=FALSE,bty="n", xaxt="n")
#First x axis
axis(1, at=seq(0.5,0.9,by=0.1), labels=c("","",0.7, 0.8, 0.9) )
mtext("Proportions", 1, at=0.9, line=2)
#Second x axis 
axis(1, line=4,at=seq(0.5,0.9,by=0.1), labels=c("","",0, 2.18, 3) )
mtext("z score", 1, at=0.9, line=6)
```

[image]