# How to fix this problem with plot with multiple axis?

Tags: r, plot

The following code is copied from this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8443820/r-multiple-x-axis-with-annotations), which works perfectly.

```
# Plot and first axis:
plot(1:10,1:10,bty="n",col="red",pch=16,axes=FALSE,xlab="",ylab="")
axis(2,0:11,las=1)
axis(1,0:11,line=1,col="red",col.ticks="red",col.axis="red")
mtext("Label 1",1,line=1,at=0.2,col="red")

# Secondary points and axis:
points(rnorm(10,50,20)/10, rnorm(10,5,2),pch=16, col="blue" )
axis(1,0:11,labels=0:11*10,line=3,col="blue",col.ticks="blue",col.axis="blue")
mtext("Label 2",1,line=3,at=0.2,col="blue")
```

However, I need to add one more for my purpose and I tried to add this following chunk:

```
points(rnorm(10,50,20)/10, rnorm(10,5,2),pch=16, col="black" )
axis(1,0:11,labels=0:11*10,line=5,col="black",col.ticks="black",col.axis="black")
mtext("Label 3",1,line=5,at=0.2,col="black")
```

Although the third plot appears but the third axis seems to go below the page and do not appear fully. Tried to change the parameters but no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create more space for the axis by increasing the number of lines of the bottom margin. The default value is 5 so you may try increasing it to 7. This has to be done before you call `plot`. See help for `par` for more details

```r
par(mar=c(7, 4, 4, 2) + .1)
```